# error in openvpn installation

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, openvpn

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openvpn-as : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 is to be installed
              Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
              Depends: libxmlsec1 (>= 1.2.33) but 1.2.28-2 is to be installed
              Depends: libxmlsec1-openssl (>= 1.2.33) but 1.2.28-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: There is no `openvpn-as` package in the Ubuntu repositories. The error is telling you that the non-Ubuntu package is **incompatible** with your release of Ubuntu, so stop trying to install it. Whatever source you added to obtain those packages, remove that source. It's unclear why you want to use non-Ubuntu packages, since there is already has a very nice, compatible, tested, secure OpenVPN package in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: You may also want to read this info https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask